# python MD5 function to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, hash, md5

I have a problem converting python md5 code to the javascript version of it; How would I write a javascript md5 function like below ?

```
from hashlib import md5
from struct import unpack

def generate_id():
    input_value = "test"
    hashed = md5(input_value).digest()
    hash1 = unpack("<q", hashed[0:8])[0]
    hash2 = unpack("<q", hashed[8:16])[0]
    return hash1 ^ hash2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what issues did you run into?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-md5

Comment: I only tried the one javascript md5 lib https://raw.githubusercontent.com/emn178/js-md5/master/src/md5.js, but that didn't work as expected. not sure how javascript generates bytes array through digest() function